# How to add fxFlex directive conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to add fxFlex directive from **@angular/flex-layout** depending on some value?

For example, I have a situation like this:

```
<div [attr.fxFlex]="someCondition"></div>
```

This does not work for me but I need fxFlex to be applied only if a condition is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add attribute then do this:

```
<div [attr.fxFlex]="someCondition ? true : null"></div>
```

But look like you want to apply directive, so the only way would be

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="someCondition"></div>
<div *ngIf="!someCondition"></div>
```